# Display BlogEngine.NET last 4 posts?

Tags: asp.net, gridview, rss, blogengine.net

I have BlogEngine.NET 2.5 installed and it works fantastic. It is installed to a subdirectory in my website.

> www.site.co.uk/blog

BE 2.5 saves the posts as XML files in the `App_Data/posts` folder.

The root of my website is based on HTML5 and I have 4 sections where i would like to grab the last 4 articles written.

Do I just write the page in ASP.NET and grab the last 4 XML files reading the "title" sections of the files and then creating the links? and put this in a Grid View control? and then style with CSS accordingly?

Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have completed this by using the following tutorial:
[Consuming RSS Feed using ASP.NET](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=137)